# dpkg not working properly

Tags: apt, dpkg, dependencies, synaptic

It all started after installing xemacs21 on my Ubuntu machine. Here are some of the outputs probably needed for troubleshooting. Let me know if I should add more.   After trying

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Gives

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up xemacs21-mule (21.4.22-14ubuntu1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/xemacs21-mule.postinst: 38: /var/lib/dpkg/info/xemacs21-mule.postinst: /usr/lib/emacsen-common/emacs-install: not found
dpkg: error processing package xemacs21-mule (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of xemacs21:
 xemacs21 depends on xemacs21-mule (>= 21.4.22-14ubuntu1) | xemacs21-mule-canna-wnn (>= 21.4.22-14ubuntu1) | xemacs21-nomule (>= 21.4.22-14ubuntu1); however:
  Package xemacs21-mule is not configured yet.
  Package xemacs21-mule-canna-wnn is not installed.
  Package xemacs21-nomule is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package xemacs21 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 xemacs21-mule
 xemacs21
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

After Trying

```
sudo apt autoremove -f
```

Gives

```
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
    1 not fully installed or removed.
    After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
    Setting up xemacs21-mule (21.4.22-14ubuntu1) ...
    /var/lib/dpkg/info/xemacs21-mule.postinst: 38: /var/lib/dpkg/info/xemacs21-mule.postinst: /usr/lib/emacsen-common/emacs-install: not found

dpkg: error processing package xemacs21-mule (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 xemacs21-mule
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

After Trying

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove xemacs21
```

Gives

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  xemacs21*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 26.6 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
(Reading database ... 260044 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing xemacs21 (21.4.22-14ubuntu1) ...
Setting up xemacs21-mule (21.4.22-14ubuntu1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/xemacs21-mule.postinst: 38: /var/lib/dpkg/info/xemacs21-mule.postinst: /usr/lib/emacsen-common/emacs-install: not found
dpkg: error processing package xemacs21-mule (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 xemacs21-mule
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

After Trying

```
sudo apt-get install dpkg
```

Gives

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
dpkg is already the newest version (1.18.4ubuntu1.2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Setting up xemacs21-mule (21.4.22-14ubuntu1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/xemacs21-mule.postinst: 38: /var/lib/dpkg/info/xemacs21-mule.postinst: /usr/lib/emacsen-common/emacs-install: not found
dpkg: error processing package xemacs21-mule (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of xemacs21:
 xemacs21 depends on xemacs21-mule (>= 21.4.22-14ubuntu1) | xemacs21-mule-canna-wnn (>= 21.4.22-14ubuntu1) | xemacs21-nomule (>= 21.4.22-14ubuntu1); however:
  Package xemacs21-mule is not configured yet.
  Package xemacs21-mule-canna-wnn is not installed.
  Package xemacs21-nomule is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package xemacs21 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                  Errors were encountered while processing:
 xemacs21-mule
 xemacs21
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

After Trying

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Gives

```
Setting up xemacs21-mule (21.4.22-14ubuntu1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/xemacs21-mule.postinst: 38: /var/lib/dpkg/info/xemacs21-mule.postinst: /usr/lib/emacsen-common/emacs-install: not found
dpkg: error processing package xemacs21-mule (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of xemacs21:
 xemacs21 depends on xemacs21-mule (>= 21.4.22-14ubuntu1) | xemacs21-mule-canna-wnn (>= 21.4.22-14ubuntu1) | xemacs21-nomule (>= 21.4.22-14ubuntu1); however:
  Package xemacs21-mule is not configured yet.
  Package xemacs21-mule-canna-wnn is not installed.
  Package xemacs21-nomule is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package xemacs21 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 xemacs21-mule
 xemacs21
```

After Trying

```
~$ sudo apt upgrade
```

Gives

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Setting up xemacs21-mule (21.4.22-14ubuntu1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/xemacs21-mule.postinst: 38: /var/lib/dpkg/info/xemacs21-mule.postinst: /usr/lib/emacsen-common/emacs-install: not found
dpkg: error processing package xemacs21-mule (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of xemacs21:
 xemacs21 depends on xemacs21-mule (>= 21.4.22-14ubuntu1) | xemacs21-mule-canna-wnn (>= 21.4.22-14ubuntu1) | xemacs21-nomule (>= 21.4.22-14ubuntu1); however:
  Package xemacs21-mule is not configured yet.
  Package xemacs21-mule-canna-wnn is not installed.
  Package xemacs21-nomule is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package xemacs21 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                  Errors were encountered while processing:
 xemacs21-mule
 xemacs21
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

After Trying

```
sudo apt-get purge --remove xemacs21*
```

[sudo] password for nipun:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'xemacs21-mule-canna-wnn' for glob 'xemacs21*'
Note, selecting 'xemacs21-mule' for glob 'xemacs21*'
Note, selecting 'xemacs21' for glob 'xemacs21*'
Note, selecting 'xemacs21-supportel' for glob 'xemacs21*'
Note, selecting 'xemacs21-basesupport-el' for glob 'xemacs21*'
Note, selecting 'xemacs21-bin' for glob 'xemacs21*'
Note, selecting 'xemacs21-mulesupport' for glob 'xemacs21*'
Note, selecting 'xemacs21-support' for glob 'xemacs21*'
Note, selecting 'xemacs21-mulesupport-el' for glob 'xemacs21*'
Note, selecting 'xemacs21-gnome-nomule' for glob 'xemacs21*'
Note, selecting 'xemacs21-gnome-mule' for glob 'xemacs21*'
Note, selecting 'xemacs21-nomule' for glob 'xemacs21*'
Note, selecting 'xemacs21-basesupport' for glob 'xemacs21*'
Note, selecting 'xemacs21-gnome-mule-canna-wnn' for glob 'xemacs21*'
Package 'xemacs21-gnome-mule' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'xemacs21-gnome-mule-canna-wnn' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'xemacs21-gnome-nomule' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'xemacs21' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'xemacs21-basesupport-el' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'xemacs21-mule-canna-wnn' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'xemacs21-mulesupport-el' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'xemacs21-nomule' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'xemacs21-supportel' is not installed, so not removed
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libcompfaceg1
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  xemacs21-basesupport* xemacs21-bin* xemacs21-mule* xemacs21-mulesupport*
  xemacs21-support*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 5 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 98.3 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
(Reading database ... 260040 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing xemacs21-mule (21.4.22-14ubuntu1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/xemacs21-mule.prerm: 19: /var/lib/dpkg/info/xemacs21-mule.prerm: /usr/lib/emacsen-common/emacs-remove: not found
dpkg: error processing package xemacs21-mule (--purge):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/xemacs21-mule to provide /usr/bin/xemacs21 (xemacs21) in auto mode
/var/lib/dpkg/info/xemacs21-mule.postinst: 38: /var/lib/dpkg/info/xemacs21-mule.postinst: /usr/lib/emacsen-common/emacs-install: not found
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
dpkg: xemacs21-mulesupport: dependency problems, but removing anyway as you requested:
 xemacs21-mule depends on xemacs21-mulesupport (>= 2003.04.23-1).

Removing xemacs21-mulesupport (2009.02.17.dfsg.2-2) ...
Purging configuration files for xemacs21-mulesupport (2009.02.17.dfsg.2-2) ...
dpkg: xemacs21-support: dependency problems, but removing anyway as you requested:
 xemacs21-bin depends on xemacs21-support (= 21.4.22-14ubuntu1).
 xemacs21-mule depends on xemacs21-support (= 21.4.22-14ubuntu1).

Removing xemacs21-support (21.4.22-14ubuntu1) ...
Purging configuration files for xemacs21-support (21.4.22-14ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: xemacs21-basesupport: dependency problems, but removing anyway as you requested:
 xemacs21-mule depends on xemacs21-basesupport (>= 2003.04.23-1); however:
  Package xemacs21-basesupport is to be removed.

Removing xemacs21-basesupport (2009.02.17.dfsg.2-2) ...
dpkg: xemacs21-bin: dependency problems, but removing anyway as you requested:
 xemacs21-mule depends on xemacs21-bin (= 21.4.22-14ubuntu1); however:
  Package xemacs21-bin is to be removed.

Removing xemacs21-bin (21.4.22-14ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for install-info (6.1.0.dfsg.1-5) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 xemacs21-mule
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
~$
```

Comment: dpkg is working perfectly, just the ubuntu guys have made another incorrect package. Feel free to fill a bugreport: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xemacs21/+bugs

Comment: `xemacs21 depends on xemacs21-mule (>= 21.4.22-14ubuntu1) | xemacs21-mule-canna-wnn (>= 21.4.22-14ubuntu1) | xemacs21-nomule (>= 21.4.22-14ubuntu1);` The lowest dependency is `xemacs21-nomule` on this error message, I had a similar issue and I just installed that one and it worked, in your case: `sudo apt install xemacs21-nomule`

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you have broken **emacsen-common** package, try to reinstall it:

```
apt-get install --reinstall emacsen-common
```

and then perform removing (with purge) all the xemacs21 packages before trying to install again.
Keep in mind it will remove all your config files so better make a backup before purging.